# Alpha-08: Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs

Tags: androidx, android-workmanager

I've looked around and the consensus is it's fixed on Alpha-07, but I'm seeing it in 08 on a 7.0 AND 8.0 device. I have network constraints so there is a possibility that given a long period of no network I could schedule more than 100 work items. I'm a little confused about how batching plays into this. Are we saying WorkManager can only schedule 100 items before it crashes or is there still a batching bug? Thanks

Code that adds to WM:

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build();
Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
        .putString(UploadWorker.DATA, data)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(inputData)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, BACK_OFF_TIME_DELAY_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addTag(TAG)
        .build();
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
workManager.enqueue(uploadWork);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of the WorkManager library (version alpha09) that should solves this issue once for all. As reported in the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes):

> Added another fix that was needed for the "100 jobs" error. [b/115560696](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115560696)

A good option to see how the WorkManager library is evolving is to keep an eye on [its issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:409906).