# Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs with JobIntentService

Tags: android, jobintentservice

Here's my `JobIntentService`

```
public class NotifierService extends JobIntentService {
     public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
         enqueueWork(context, NotifierService.class, JOB_ID, work);
     }

     protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
         //simple if/else check
     }
}
```

However, I got many crashes from the crashlytics which complained about `100 distinct jobs`:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
   at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:211)
```

Is there any reason to solve it?

I had tried to cancel it before enqueuing the new one as below:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            if (scheduler != null) {
                for (JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs()) {
                    if (jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID) {
                        scheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I got another issue:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given work is not active: JobWorkItem{id=1 intent=Intent { cmp=com.my.test.package/.notifier.NotifierService } dcount=1}
   at android.app.job.JobParameters.completeWork(JobParameters.java:221)
```

Do you guys have any suggestion?

P/s: I could not reproduce it on my devices, but I got it thousand times in CrashReport tool. Canceling work before enqueuing the new work did solve the 100 distinct jobs issue, but it raised another bug as above.

Comment: Any help for this? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with my implementation. All finished jobs are somehow created over again if I start a new job. I'm on 2.0.1. It's supposedly fixed in some earlier alpha version as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286698/alpha-08-apps-may-not-schedule-more-than-100-distinct-jobs but I don't think so.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?